# CSV Export in SSRS 2008 R2 Issue with Column Name

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am exporting to CSV format in SSRS 2008 R2. The only issue i have is if i have a condition like the following, it actually outputs A as column header, rather than B or C. Is there any way to resolve this please?

```
IIF(A=true, B, C)
```

Comment: Have you tried exporting the report in excel format?

Comment: User needs it in CSV and not excel.

Comment: If it exports OK to Excel it can then be saved in csv format

Comment: This is not a meaningful question with such a vague description and no indication of how the source report is constructed.